# Animate background on list scroll

Tags: android, android-animation

What I'm trying to achieve is a fade in/out animation on a background image.

I have an activity like this:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".DayOverview"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/dayOverviewBg"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/bg_home" />

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" >

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/dayOverview_pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/px40"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/px20"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/px20" />

        <com.google.ads.AdView
            xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
            android:id="@+id/dayOverviewAd"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
            app:adUnitId="xx-xxx-x...xxxxxxxxx" />

    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

and for each page of the `ViewPager` a fragment with a `ListView`, what I want is to change the image in the activity when the ListView scrolls with a fade effect.

I looked around for something like this but all I could find is how to make something like the `parallax effect` on the home screen of android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried looking into the [AbsListView.OnScrollListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.OnScrollListener.html) interface? Basically, it gets triggered everytime your listview is scrolled. You can then get the first visible item in the list using the [getFirstVisiblePosition()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#getFirstVisiblePosition%28%29) method, perform your calculations and eventually, change your background.

For achieving a cross-fade effect for switching backgrounds, you may use a [TransitionDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/TransitionDrawable.html)

Here's an example:

```
            TransitionDrawable transitionDrawable = new TransitionDrawable(new Drawable[]{
                    mLockscreenBg.getDrawable(),    // current background drawable
                    fetchedDrawable                 // new drawable
            });

            mLockscreenBg.setImageDrawable(transitionDrawable);
            mLockscreenBg.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            transitionDrawable.setCrossFadeEnabled(true);   // this is optional, but it delivers a better animation
            transitionDrawable.startTransition(mShortAnimDuration);
```

Comment: I'm still not able to stop the transition when the scroll stops, how do i calculate the duration of the animation?

Comment: You're already explicitly providing the animation duration in the `startTransition(int duration)` method. Are you continuously trying to update the background or only when the scrolling stops?

Comment: I need a partial transition based on how much the list is scrolled while i'm scrolling

Comment: Ohkay.. that might not be possible. If you only plan to animate transition between two imageviews, try playing with the alpha values. For instance, reduce the alpha value of 1st image and increase that of the 2nd image while the list is being scrolled down.

Comment: Ok i'll try it tomorrow and see how it looks

Comment: sorry for the late response, thank you it worked as I needed.

Comment: Glad I was able to help :)